# insert select statement inside a from statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
    SELECT TOP 3 (*)
    FROM TA
    WHERE TA.X = 'derp'
```

basically I want an upper limit on my query before I count, so I need to insert it inside the FROM, but I can't seem to get the syntax right; Would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: mysql != sql server, especially in that case (TOP or LIMIT). So which one you need ?

Comment: SQL-Server or MySQL?? make a choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql server :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT TOP 3 *
      FROM TA
      WHERE TA.X = 'derp') as t
```

Mysql

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (SELECT NULL 
      FROM TA
      WHERE TA.X = 'derp'
      LIMIT 3) as t
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very confusing.  But assuming you're asking how to construct a sub-query, then you need to use parentheses around the query and alias the results:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
   (
    SELECT TOP 3 *
    FROM TA
    WHERE TA.X = 'derp'
   ) TableAlias
```